# Elasticsearch uses much more disk space then it shown in info about indices stat

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch (in docker) uses much more disk space than it shown in the info about indices stat.

It shows only 7.8gb

```
curl 'localhost:9201/_cat/indices?v'
health status index         uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   my_index LL319QgqSJ6FNDEh2ZQw8g   1   1   24896180            0      7.8gb          7.8gb
yellow open   test          u0IJ7cocSXSlRST_qCPhHg   1   1          8            0      5.5kb          5.5kb
```

but when I see the disk space info inside the docker container I see the following

```
    docker exec -it es bash
    df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         278G   51G  213G  20% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1       278G   51G  213G  20% /etc/hosts
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/firmware
```

I`ve found such a command.

```
curl 'localhost:9201/_cat/allocation?v' 
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent host ip node 
2 7.8gb 65gb 212.6gb 277.6gb 23 172.17.0.2 172.17.0.2 571fa89f411f 2 UNASSIGNED
```

But I cant understand what ES spends 65-7.8~57gb of disk space?

As I understood, disk.used shows 'Elasticsearch, including the translog and unassigned shards; The node’s OS; Any other applications or files on the node'. How can I decrease consumption of the disk?